# Wie sagt man " It's only a matter of time"auf Deutsch

Tags: grammar

> Es handelt sich nur um die Zeit, dass sie herausfinden, dass ich nach
>   Deutschland herüberkomme.

```
It's only a matter of time that they will find out I am coming over to Germany.
```

Ist`Es handelt sich um nur eine Zeit` eine richtige Übersetzung für `It's only a matter of time`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be: "Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit, bis Sie herausfinden, dass ich nach Deutschland komme". Title Answer would be: "Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit".

Comment: When can I use "Es handelt sich um die Zeit, dass...*?

Comment: There is no "Es handelt sich um die Zeit, dass ..." , as it would mean as much as "It is about the time, as ..." You could say "Ist just a question of time, until ..." which would be " Es ist nur eine Frage der Zeit, bis ... "